# JUni5 MockitoExtension and changing the mock type to use a concrete one

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

Let's say that I have an interface `FooService` and a class `FooServiceImpl` that implements the former.
I want to use in a test

```java
@Mock
FooService
```

and get a mock of the class `FooServiceImpl` and not of the type `FooService`.

To do that, I have a static registry with all the mappings.
Now, I was wondering if I can somehow hack the `MockitoExtension` class for JUnit5 to do that.
Ideally, this should happen in `IndependentAnnotationEngine` or in `MockAnnotationProcessor` but I haven't found a proper way to do it yet.

How can I jump into the `MockitoExtension` to change how Mockito creates mocks?

Comment: If you want a mock of `FooServiceImpl` and not `FooService`, why not just type `@Mock FooServiceImpl`?

Comment: As I wrote, I have a static registry with all the mappings (and another one where the instances are statically set), so somewhere in the code we may need to access the real implementation.

Comment: Please, don't start suggesting refactoring the code base, it has a lot of legacy and 1MLN lines of code, I simply cannot do it.

Comment: So FooServiceImpl has public methods which are not on FooService, but need to be used in your unit tests?

Comment: @tgdavies no, it is more subtle. We use only the methods from the interface.

The reason for such attempt is that we have i) a static context that delivers the instance for the interface , ii) mocks of the interface must be of the concrete type when set in the context and for this reason we cannot accept the ones declared by the interface.

Comment: You could initialize your mocks manually in a `@BeforeEach` method (and drop `@Mock` extension). In this initalization method, call `Mockito.mock`. You can reach your registry to look up concrete implementation class.